# Next JS rewrites not being applied in getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm having a problem with rewrites in getServerSideProps in Next JS.

I have the following rewrite in `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/api/:path*",
                destination: "http://localhost:5000/api/:path*",
            },
        ];
    },
};
```

This works everywhere, except for in `getServerSideProps`, where it doesn't get recognized.

```js
// axios instance used throughout the app
const axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: "/api",
});

// checkout.tsx
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const res = await axios.get("/cart");
    return {props: {data: res.data}}
}
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

The `_currentUrl` from axios is `http:/api/cart` when I checked it. Is there any reason that my rewrites is only failing in `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: You need to use absolute URLs for requests on the server-side. As you can see, axios is not making the request against the correct endpoint `http:/api/cart`.

Comment: axios makes the correct request when I use it in a `useEffect` using relative URLs. I'm wondering why the rewrites don't get applied in `getServerSideProps` but do in `useEffect`?

Comment: As I said, you have to use absolute URLs in your requests on the server-side.

Comment: @juliomalves how to achieve that? I know what you mean but should we duplicate API calls? one for client-side without baseUrl and one for server-side with absolute URL?

Comment: @AliBaghban If you're doing the request in both client and server, then yes there will be duplication.